# How to make the length of y axis longer in histogram in R

Tags: r

I have used the following code to generate the histogram. However, I want to make the y axis longer since it is too short, may I know how to do it?

```
> h<-hist(data, breaks=c(0,1, 2, 3, 4), col="grey",xlim = c(0,4), xlab="",xaxt="n",main="")
> axis(side=1, at=0.5:3.5, labels=c(1,2,3,4))
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You could use `ylim` parameter to `hist`:

```
hist(mtcars$mpg, ylim=c(0,15))
```

`c(0,15)` gives the range to y axis.

A graph will fill whole available area (i.e. window). You could limit that by using `layout`.

```
layout(matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3), 3, 3, byrow = TRUE))
hist(mtcars$mpg, ylim=c(0,15))
```

Comment: I mean the size of y axis, like three times longer than x axis, not the range of y axis

Comment: Click the corner of your viewing window and drag it as long as you want.